# my function that checks if something is already in the database isn't working

Tags: php, mariadb

I'm working on this project and I need help with something. I am trying to check if someone is already in the database upon logging in and if they are not, they will be added. However, my code always adds them to the database...

Login code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["emaillogin"]) and isset($_POST["passwordlogin"])){
    $sql = "SELECT `accnr` 
            FROM `Account` 
            WHERE '$emaillogin' = `emailadress` 
            AND '$passwordlogin' = `password` LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($result == false){
        echo "E-mail or password incorrect! <br>";
    }else{
        $accnr = mysql_fetch_array($result);                    
        setcookie("accnr", $accnr[0] , time() + (1800), "/"); 
        $accnmr = $accnr[0];

        if(check_firstest($accnmr) == false){
            $query = "INSERT INTO `VRIENDEN`
                               (`accnr`,`vriendnr`) 
                        VALUES ('$accnmr','$accnmr')";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
        }

        header("location:home.php");
        die();
    }
}
```

?>

The function in functions.php:

```
function check_firstest($accnr){    
$query = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) AS 'num' FROM `VRIENDEN` WHERE `accnr` = '$accnr' AND `vriendnr` = '$accnr'");
    if($result > 0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The login on its own works just fine, so thats no problem.
Thank you!

Comment: `mysql_query` returns a resource, not the output from the query. You need to use a fetch function on that result.

Comment: mysql is deprecated , start using mysqli

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Plain Text Password **Very bad idea**  PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is somewhat odd and you do not capture the values from $_POST into the variables that you are using in the query either

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(isset($_POST["emaillogin"]) and isset($_POST["passwordlogin"])){
    $sql = "SELECT `accnr` 
            FROM `Account` 
            WHERE `emailadress` = '{$_POST['emaillogin']}'
            AND   `password` = '{$_POST['passwordlogin']}'
            LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($result == false){
        // something went REALLY WRONG, report it
        echo mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
    if ( mysql_num_rows($result) == 1 ) {
        // found user and password matches
        header("location:home.php");
        exit;
    }else{
        // new user, create the account
        $accnr = mysql_fetch_array($result);                    
        setcookie("accnr", $accnr[0] , time() + (1800), "/"); 
        $accnmr = $accnr[0];

        if(check_firstest($accnmr) == false){
            $query = "INSERT INTO `VRIENDEN`
                               (`accnr`,`vriendnr`) 
                        VALUES ('$accnmr','$accnmr')";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
        }
        // and go to home page
        header("location:home.php");
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

And of course the fix for the `check_firstest()` is also required

```
function check_firstest($accnr){    
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) AS 'num' 
                            FROM `VRIENDEN` 
                            WHERE `accnr` = '$accnr' 
                            AND `vriendnr` = '$accnr'");
    if(mysql_fetch_field($result, 0) > 0){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

> But I have to add
>
> Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
>   Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
>   [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
>
> And
>
> You should not be using the `mysql_` database extension, it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
>   If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
>   [Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I have literally done all of this and still it won't add to the database when there is nothing in there...

Comment: I just added a bit of error checking, try this code again

Comment: error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '} AND `password` = 'hh' LIMIT 1' at line 3

Comment: Silly me! I forgot the quotes around the text variables. See amended code for first query

Comment: Welp... nothing happens. it just logs in and thats it. It doesn't add anything to the databse. It just logs in. It doesn't give me an error code or something

Comment: I am assuming you always want to go to `home.php` when user exists, and once a user has been created. Try above amendment

Answer (score -1):

You have to count the resulting rows:

```
function check_firstest($accnr){    
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) AS 'num' 
                            FROM `VRIENDEN` 
                            WHERE `accnr` = '$accnr' 
                            AND `vriendnr` = '$accnr'");
    if(mysql_fetch_field($result, 0) > 0){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here the mysql_num_rows() function gives the number of rows in the result set. If it is greater than 0 then it means that there is some data.

Comment: Won't that always be at least `1`? `COUNT` will always return a row.

Comment: This will always return TRUE! Suggest you fix it

Comment: @JonStirling How would you suggest to fix it then?

Comment: Please go through the official manual @http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php
It clearly says `The number of rows in a result set on success or FALSE on failure.`

Comment: Apparently @RiggsFolly fixed the answer for you.

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal We're well aware of how it works. I'd suggest you re-read it, alongside reading up about the SQL `COUNT` function.

Comment: I have amended your answer, as it got UV from those who have not had enough coffee yet this morning

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal I suggest you also apply a little logic! When the answer to the COUNT query is Zero(0) you still get ONE ROW RETURNED with the result of ZERO in it

Comment: but if there's nothing in the database yet, it won't add it.

Comment: @literallyme that is because you are holding the result of `mysql_query` in the variable $query and checking it against $result.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I got it.. ;)

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal Excellent :)